# When it's not appropriate to store Key values in a .config

Tags: asp.net, .net

I'm always battling the decision whether to store a constant (key) value in a C# class or .config file.

Is there a good hard rule that says don't store constants in the web.config?  In other words, what are the disadvantages to storing what type of values in a .config vs. a constant in a class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constants, by definition, do not change. These are things like pi and who kidnapped the Lindbergh baby. There is no need to store these in a config file, as if they can change then they are not constant.

If the value can change (i.e. is not constant), then store it in a config file or some other user-configurable area.

Answer (score 2):

If you think you could want it to change without a recomplile, put it in a config file. Otherwise make it a constant.

One case that comes to mind is dynamically choosing the right connection string based on a name. Sometimes its easier to store it as a constant, but its not as flexible as actually naming it.